# How to get my required record with defined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi my table structure is shown as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLadY.png)

and with sql query I want to make it as below structure format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHskN.png)

I have to make this with single sql query.

Currently I had made this with excel feature
Can I get any suggestion?

```
Questionid  Response        Response
   1        HighlyEngaged   HighlyEngaged
   2        VeryPrepared    VeryPrepared
   2        VeryPrepared1   VeryPrepared1

 to

 RowLabels        Count of Response
  1                1
  HighlyEngaged    1
  2                2 
  VeryPrepared     1
  VeryPrepared1    1
```

Comment: Insted of posting pictures is better to copy/paste the files info. Could you do that?

Comment: @jalazbe i had updated please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared following query, I think it can help you :

```
DROP TABLE QA
GO
CREATE TABLE QA
(
    Questionid  INT
    ,Response   VARCHAR(100) 
)

INSERT INTO QA
    VALUES(1,'HighlyEngaged')
   ,(2,'VeryPrepared' )
   ,(5,'Asked' )
   ,(5,'Priority' )
   ,(5,'Explained' )
   ,(8,'Yes' )
   ,(9,'Set Agenda' )
   ,(9,'Take Atten' )
   ,(11,'Assigned')
   ,(11,'Individual')
   ,(12,'Predict')
   ,(12,'Questions')

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN Response = '' THEN CAST(QuestionId AS VARCHAR)
        ELSE ''
    END QId
   ,Response
   ,ResponseTotal
FROM (SELECT
        QuestionId
       ,'' Response
       ,COUNT(Response) ResponseTotal
    FROM QA
    GROUP BY QuestionId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        QuestionId
       ,Response
       ,COUNT(1)
    FROM QA
    GROUP BY QuestionId
            ,Response) a
ORDER BY QuestionId, CASE
    WHEN Response = '' THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
drop table #teee
CREATE TABLE #teee
    ([Questionid] int, [Response] varchar(13), [Response1] varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO #teee
    ([Questionid], [Response], [Response1])
VALUES
    (1, 'HighlyEngaged', 'HighlyEngaged'),
    (2, 'VeryPrepared', 'VeryPrepared'),
    (2, 'VeryPrepared1', 'VeryPrepared1')
;

select res,cnt from (select [Questionid],cast([Questionid]as varchar(100)) res ,count([Response]) cnt from #teee
group by [Questionid]
union all
select [Questionid],cast([Response]as varchar(100)) res,count([Response]) r1 from #teee
group by [Questionid],[Response])a
order by [Questionid],res
```

the following is an update for the answer given by [Yogesh Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53337485/how-to-get-my-required-record-with-defined-table/53337529#53337529)

```
select isnull([Response],[Questionid]),total from (select [Questionid], [Response], count(*) total
from #teee t  
group by [Questionid], [Response] with rollup) a
where  isnull([Response],[Questionid]) is not null
order by [Questionid],1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `roll up` with aggregation :

```
select questionid, Response, count(*)
from table t  
group by questionid, Response with roll up;
```

Comment: No its not populating the record as I needed, and I need only 2 rows i.e. Row Label and Count of Response

Comment: @miteshjain. . . I know that's not same, but you should know `excel` <> `SQL Server`. `SQL Server` is Database tool not a data presentation tool.